# Using multiple API vs reading from a file

Tags: python, database, api

I am doing a python project that would use multiple python API (At least 3) to obtain datas from a lot of countries and I am wondering if it is more efficient to for the data using the APIs or to use the APIs once to make a file and access it later, when needed.

Comment: a lot of APIs have access limitations,  for example number of times you can hit them per day.  Approach I use is to normalise data into pandas data frames then serialise into a Redis cache and set expire time in cache. Then always use from cache and fetch if not in cache.   This is also *a lot* faster

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always better to handle data management in your back end to minimize the performance loss in your front end.